# How to find the index of specific value in a vector?

Tags: matlab

I have a 100*20 matrix called pr (power receive in my case) the 100 represent number of users and 20 number of antennas each user receive certain power from the 20 antennas.(more than one user could receive power from the same  antenna). 
then i find the maximum power each user receive and put it in a 100*1 vector If this maximum values greater than (-112) counter increase. I need to create new vector 20*1 where 20 is the antennas number and count the number of users that receive power greater than(-112) for each antenna

```
[master_ant,id]=max(pr,[],2); %find vector of max values and vector of the corresponding index
  for i=1:100
if(master_ant(i)>=-112) %check the rang
    covered_user=covered_user+1;%counter increment
end
end
```

i tried this

```
[master_ant,id]=max(pr,[],2);
  for i=1:100
if(master_ant(i)>=-112)
    covered_user(id)=covered_user(id)+1;
```

Comment: This is a bit hard to understand. Can you give an example with some small vectors? 15x1, and you need a vector with 5 values or something? And what exactly isn't working? Also, your code are identical (except for the missing `end`.

Comment: I'll answer the other point when you have answered my comments, but for now: your code can be simplified to: 

    `[master_ant, id] = max(pr, [], 2);
    covered_user = sum(master_ant >= -112);`

Comment: or `covered_user = numel(find(master_ant >= -112));` But it is probably worse than @StewieGriffin's answer

Comment: max       index                                                                                          3             2                                                                                             5             2                                                                                       4             2                                                                                                i need to say that index two have three values

Comment: I'm still not able to understand exactly what you want. It would be nice if you add a complete example. with the input `pr`, and the desired output/outputs. Please update the question, and not put too much information in the comments. =)

Comment: @m.muner Are you trying to do a histogram? In that case, over what entities?

Comment: x = [1,1,1,2,4,5,5]

I need an output

y = [3,1,0,1,2]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to consider another approach. The function `sum`, can actually (and is supposed to) do all the job for you.

```
a = randi([-130, -60],100,20); % Example matrix
covered_user = sum(a>=-112); % One-liner solution
```